# Find the area of the region that is bounded by $r = \cos(\theta)$ from $0$ to $\pi/6$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

> Find the area of the region that is bounded by $r = \cos(\theta)$ from $0$ to $\pi/6$.

I'm pretty confident that I know what I am doing for this problem but I just want to make sure I have it down.

Evaluating the integral left me with $(1/4) [\theta + \sin(2\theta)/2]$ from $0$ to $\pi/6$

My answer is $\pi/24 + \sqrt{3}/16$

Could anyone confirm that I'm doing this right? I don't have any other way of checking really...

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the area in polar coordinate is:
$$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}r^{2}(\theta)d\theta$$
then
$$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\cos^{2}(\theta)d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{1+\cos2\theta}{2}d\theta=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})}{2}-\frac{\sin0}{2}\right)=$$
$$A=\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{24}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{16}$$
in conclution your answer is correct.

God bless you.